# Using python-amazon-simple-product-api to extract lowest used goods price

Tags: python, api, amazon-product-api

I am learning to use python to extract used book price by `python-amazon-simple-product-api`

Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
amazon = AmazonAPI(aws_access_key, 
                   aws_secret_key,
                   aws_associate_key)

# products = amazon.search(Keywords=book_demanded_df['isbn01'].values[1], SearchIndex='Books')
products = amazon.search(Keywords='B00CU0NSCU', SearchIndex='All')

# print book_demanded_df['isbn01'].values[1]
for i, product in enumerate(products):
    print product.title
    print product.asin
    print product.get_attribute('Manufacturer')    
    print product.get_attributes(['ItemDimensions.Width', 'ItemDimensions.Height'])
    print product.offer_url
```

I think the key should be at `get_attributes`, I tried writing something lik `ItemAttributes.Amount`, but things seems to be not working.

Is it possible to do so using this API?

Answer (score 2):

i'm the author of this little library. The amazon API response is quite a mess, and varies depending on the product you are querying for. In the example above the ASIN belongs to a Kindle Fire 7" Tablet family of products. It includes version with 8gb and 16gb memory, each with a different ASIN. For example, the ASIN of the 8gb version in B007T36S34.

As for the used price, the API does not support this at the moment, but you can use this as a work around:

```
>>> products[0]._safe_get_element_text(('OfferSummary.LowestUsedPrice.FormattedPrice'))
'$84.99'
>>> products[0]._safe_get_element_text(('OfferSummary.LowestUsedPrice.CurrencyCode'))
'USD'
```

Its useful to look at the [Amazon Product Advertising API documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CHAP_response_elements.html) when searching for data such as this.